# RJS error in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rjs

Why does this:

```
    <%= update_page_tag do |page|
    page["femenino"].hide
  end %>
```

Generates this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
try {
$("femenino").hide();
} catch (e) { alert('RJS error:\n\n' + e.toString()); alert('$(\"femenino\").hide();'); throw e }
//]]>
</script>
```

I have the DIV with ID "femenino", the update_page_tag is located after the DIV and it works but I dont like to look at that error in the source code.

Thanks

Comment: It works but if I look at the source code I get:

catch (e) { alert('RJS error:\n\n' + e.toString());

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the `config.action_view.debug_rjs` option is enabled, rails will wrap most of the javascript generated from PrototypeHelper in a try/catch block.
By default `config.action_view.debug_rjs` is enabled in development mode only, so check your `config/environments/production.rb` file if you're seeing this in production.

Comment: Ooo thanks, I've only run the app in development so I'll check that when is in production.